# How to show image like video in facebook

Tags: facebook, image, video

I want to ask about how to show image like video in facebook
Look if you post this link in facebook post area will show you video but no video in [this link](http://www.nmisr.com/video-photos/141192).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video is specified via the Open Graph meta tags, as you can see here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nmisr.com%2Fvideo-photos%2F141192

See here for more information what specific OG meta tags you need for this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#media

Comment: Thank you @CBroe for answer me
but i have just one more question .
Do I need a apps or just put the meta tags in the head ?

Comment: You just need to put the meta tags into the head section of the HTML document. After that, check your implementation using the debug tool I linked to, it will tell you if everything is OK, or if you have errors that need to be corrected.